# Windows form VB.NET & Telerik Rad WinForms(2011)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, telerik, telerik-window

I am working on a simple window application (VS2010,VB.NET). It's an HR management App  - Employees records.

I need simply insert/edit Employee Info, reports in Excel (with out crystal reports) & Show in Grid.

So I am thinking of using Telerik RAD WinForms (2011) only because it looks cool.

But I also know that Telerik could be a real pain when you need more flexibility.

Although my application is quite basic still I want to determine whether I should go with Telerik or just use standard Windows Forms functionality?

How can I generate custom report in specific format.

Also It would be nice if some one point me to some sample application or VB.NET windows Tutorials?

You guys are awesome ,Keep It up :)

Comment: Telerik does not have built in pdf/excel export of grids, if you did not buy any Telerik library yet, I would give a try to DevExpress controls, their GridView is feature rich and has zero code printing and export functionality: http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/winforms-features.xml

Comment: Actually Telerik does have export for Excel, CSV, PDF and HTML built right in.  Works like a champ, if you are using winforms look here: http://goo.gl/EZD9C  They also have examples for WPF as well.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Telerik RadControls for WinForms support export to the mentioned excel, CSV, PDF and HTML formats and this is achieved by just a few lines of code: http://goo.gl/5GU14. As a matter of fact, I cannot really agree with your statement that Telerik controls are not flexible. In fact, I find the winforms control quite flexible. You can always download a trial and give it a try.